# How do I convert existing content on a Github page to a new Jekyll theme?

Tags: git, github, jekyll, github-pages

Hoping someone out there can help me, I have scoured the boards already. I'm not a total noob, but I'm just slightly higher than that.

I set up a Github static page 2 years back. Just a simple page, tweaked the CSS a bit from the existing templates, added an image, text and links. Got the site to work, even figured out how to point it to a custom URL.

Now, I'd like to redesign the site and use a Jekyll theme.

All the tutorials I've found talk about how to start this from scratch. How do I take the site I've already created and apply a Jekyll theme to it?

I've also read that I should be keeping the Jekyll theme in master and pulling content from gh-pages. Master is the live source of my content, and if I apply Jekyll to master, will it affect the look of my live site? I don't want that, I want to be able to work locally and make changes.

Any insight on how to accomplish this redesign is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: now, you can as well use the branch master only, if you have the code in a public repo, could you share the link? or more information about the actual code structure that you have.

Comment: but general (for a default them), the style and them stuff are in `_assets` and `_sass` . the blog posts, in `_posts` and the pages could be in the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

The content for Jekyll sites is organised into ['posts'](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/) and ['pages'](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pages/).  Which can be in html or markdown format.  Jekyll prescribes [this directory structure](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/).

If your github-pages sites is a [User Page it can only be published from `master`](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/)  (and overwriting it with a jekyll theme would therefore change your live page assuming the new site builds properly).

Otherwise you [set the publishing branch in the repo settings.](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/#enabling-github-pages-to-publish-your-site-from-master-or-gh-pages)

To work with jekyll locally just follow [these instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-your-github-pages-site-locally-with-jekyll/).  It includes the ability to run a local-only server, so that you can "preview your local Jekyll site in your web browser at http://localhost:4000."